# How to convert a 'raw' string into a 'decoded' string in Python?

Tags: python, string, type-conversion, rawstring

I have the following string:

```
raw_text  = r"The Walt Disney Company, (2006\u2013present)"    
print(raw_text)
#result : The Walt Disney Company, (2006\u2013present)
```

My questions is how can I get a decoded string "decoded_text" from the raw_text so I can get

```
print(decoded_text)
#result : The Walt Disney Company, (2006-present)
```

except this trivial way:

```
decoded_text = raw_text.replace("\u2013", "-")
```

In fact, I have big strings, which contains a lot of \u-- stuff (like \u2013, \u00c9, and so forth). So I'm looking for a way to convert all of them at once in a right way.

Comment: If your input actually comes from a Python raw string literal, `r` prefix and everything, then just take the `r` off. If your input does not come from a Python raw string literal, then the operation you're asking for is probably subtly wrong. Where *does* this input come from?

Comment: I got the string from a web through BeautifulSoup. The string contains lots of that stuff in it.

Comment: Escaping rules vary from context to context, and something that parses Python string literal escapes will do the wrong thing for, say, JSON string escaping.

Answer (score 0):

You might use built-in [codecs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) module for this task as follows

```
import codecs
raw_text  = r"The Walt Disney Company, (2006\u2013present)"
print(codecs.unicode_escape_decode(raw_text)[0])
```

output:

```
The Walt Disney Company, (2006–present)
```